# Countexample: Sum and Product of two non-zero nilpotent operators is nilpotent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, examples-counterexamples

I am asked to come up with a proof or a counterexample of the following two statements:

1. The sum of two non-zero nilpotent matrices is nilpotent.
2. The product of two non-zero nilpotent matrices is nilpotent.

I think both of these claims are false, and a counterexample exists, but I can't seem to come up with one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both claims are indeed false. you can look at:
$$A_1 =\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}\space\space\space
A_2=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\
1 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$(A_1)^2 = (A_2)^2 = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\
0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
and thus, both matrices are nilpotent, but
$$A_1+A_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$(A_1+A_2)^2 = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
and thus, for any n $\ge2$ $(A_1+A_2)^n=I$, Which is not nilpotent.
$$A_1A_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
and for any n $\ge2$ $(A_1A_2)^n=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}$ , Which again, is not nilpotent.